# Error no match for unique or primary key in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 --Create Flight schedule table
    CREATE TABLE FlightSchedule
    (RouteID VarChar(6),
    FlightDate DATE NOT NULL,
    PlaneSerial VarChar(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FlightIDDATEPK PRIMARY KEY(RouteID, FlightDate),
    CONSTRAINT FlightNoFK FOREIGN KEY(RouteID)
        REFERENCES ROUTE(RouteID),
    CONSTRAINT PlaneSerialFK FOREIGN KEY(PlaneSerial)
        REFERENCES AIRPLANE(PlaneSerial));

    --Create Crew table
    CREATE TABLE Crew
    (EmpID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    RouteID Varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    FlightDate DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT EMPIDPK PRIMARY KEY(EmpID, RouteID, FlightDate),
    CONSTRAINT EMPIDFK FOREIGN KEY(EmpID)
        REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EmpID),
    CONSTRAINT RouteIDFK FOREIGN KEY(RouteID)
        REFERENCES ROUTE(RouteID),
    CONSTRAINT DATEFK FOREIGN KEY(FlightDate)
        REFERENCES FlightSchedule(FlightDate));
```

I am trying to create 2 table but received the following error. Have set the primary key already but have no idea what is wrong.

```
Error at Command Line : 26 Column : 28
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
*Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
           gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
           key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
           catalog view
```

Comment: Does every of `EMPLOYEE`, `FlightSchedule` have a corresponding UQ/PK?

Comment: they have their own PK in another table

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys need to reference all of the columns of the parent table's primary key (or all the columns of the unique constraint that you are referencing).  If the primary key of `FlightSchedule` is `RouteID, FlightDate`, the foreign key of `Crew` that references `FlightSchedule` would need to use both columns of the primary key

```
CONSTRAINT DATEFK FOREIGN KEY(RouteID, FlightDate)
    REFERENCES FlightSchedule(RouteID, FlightDate)
```

Of course, you'd need to ensure that all your foreign keys reference the complete key from the parent table.  You haven't posted the definitions of the other tables that you're referencing so I don't know whether more of your foreign keys have the same issue.